# How to dynamically create new todo list page with user inputs submitted from form

Tags: javascript, html

I am building  a To-Do-List program in html, css and js.

I want a new project window to appear, containing the user's project name and description after the user clicks the submit button on the form after add project button is clicked.

However I don't see the values for `inputName` nor `inputDescription`. What am I doing wrong?

live code : (https://codepen.io/nolimitz71/pen/QWmBpPm?editors=1010)

JS:

```
const cancelButton = document.getElementById("cancel");
const projectForm = document.getElementById("projectForm");
const newPage = document.querySelector('.add-project');
const inputName = document.getElementById('project-name');
const inputDescription = document.getElementById('project-description');
const examplePage = document.querySelector(".example-page");
const createdContainer = document.createElement("div");
const projectHolder = document.querySelector(".item-placement");
const createdProject = document.createElement("button");
const container = document.querySelector(".body");

/*Controlling new Project form Open and Close*/
const closeProject = () => {
    projectForm.style.display = "none";
};
const openProject = () => {
    projectForm.style.display = "block";
};

newPage.addEventListener("click", openProject);

cancelButton.addEventListener("click", closeProject);


const subProjects = (() => {
    createdProject.setAttribute("id","change");
    createdProject.innerHTML = 
    `
    <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    ${inputName.value}
    `
    projectHolder.appendChild(createdProject);
})();

const LoadProject = (() => {
    createdContainer.setAttribute("id",'new-subpage');
    createdContainer.setAttribute("data-tab-content", "");
    container.appendChild(createdContainer);

    const paraName = document.createElement('p');
    paraName.textContent= inputName.value;
    paraName.classList.add("new-paragraph");
    createdContainer.appendChild(paraName);

    const paraDesc = document.createElement('p');
    paraDesc.textContent= inputDescription.value;
    paraDesc.classList.add('new-description');
    createdContainer.appendChild(paraDesc);

    const newTasks = document.createElement('button');
    newTasks.textContent = "Add Task!"
    newTasks.classList.add("new-btn");
    createdContainer.appendChild(newTasks);

    const defaultTask = document.createElement("div");
    defaultTask.classList.add("item");
    defaultTask.innerHTML= `
    <input class = "check" type="checkbox">
    <p>Default Task</p>
    <div class = 'item-btn'>
       <ion-icon class = "black" name="pencil-outline"></ion-icon>
       <ion-icon class = "black"name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>
    </div>
 </div>`
    createdContainer.appendChild(defaultTask);
})();

addPage.addEventListener("click", () => {
    examplePage.style.display = "none";
    createdContainer.style.display = "block";
})

export {closeProject, LoadProject, openProject};
```

Comment: and where exactly is the function that's called on submit ?

Comment: That's the issue I'm working on, LoadProject is the function creating the page but calling it with on submit does not solve anything.